# Writing XML records one at a time

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

I am working with a very large data set so need to write records to an xml file one at a time.

I have tried this code:

```
using (FileStream retryFile = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
{
    var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Record));

    foreach(var item in veryLargeEnumerable)
    {
        ser.Serialize(retryFile, item, emptyNamespaces);
    }
}
```

This writes the record but between every record it adds:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

When I try to read the file I get invalid format error.

How can I serialize objects one at a time to XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code shown in your question generates an invalid `xml` hierarchy;
it doesn't contain a single root element, as each `<Record>` gets written at the root level, eg.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Record>
  <Name>foo</Name>
</Record><?xml version="1.0"?>
<Record>
  <Name>bar</Name>
</Record><?xml version="1.0"?>
<Record>
  <Name>baz</Name>
</Record>
```

You'll have to construct a single root element first.
Use an [`XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=netframework-4.7.1) to do so, and then use that same `XmlWriter` as target to serialize the records into.

```
using (FileStream retryFile = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(retryFile))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Records");

    var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Record));

    /* Your loop goes here. */ 

    ser.Serialize(xmlWriter, new Record { Name = "foo" }, emptyNamespaces);
    ser.Serialize(xmlWriter, new Record { Name = "bar" }, emptyNamespaces);
    ser.Serialize(xmlWriter, new Record { Name = "baz" }, emptyNamespaces);

    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
}

public class Record 
{ 
    public string Name {get; set; } 
}
```

The `xml` wil then look like below, having a single root element `<Records>` containing the `<Record>` child elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Records>
    <Record><Name>foo</Name></Record>
    <Record><Name>bar</Name></Record>
    <Record><Name>baz</Name></Record>
</Records>
```